# EF Code First is creating query with wrong columns

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using EF 6.0 and creating my database views using code first. I have a small sample that works fine. I'm trying to migrate to another set of views. For some reason I am getting the wrong column name on the query for one of the columns. It seems to be bring in the column from the other view I'm joining to.

I've tried to change the [Key] columns on the tables but it just doesn't seem to change.

The view vABC consists of columns: name varchar(30) and desc varchar(100)
The view vXYZ consists of columns: name varchar(30) and amount float

They will join to each other on name.

This is a snippet of the query I am running:

```
             var name = dataRecord.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
             var query = from b in _context.XYZ
                        .Where(b => b.name == name)
                        select b;
```

This is returning:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[name] AS [name], 
    [Extent1].[amount] AS [amount],  
    [Extent1].[ABC_name] AS [ABC_name]
    FROM [dbo].[vXYZ] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[name] = @p__linq__0
```

I will attached the classes and dbcontext below.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Mynamespace
{

    [Table("vABC")]
    public class ABC
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public ABC()
        {
            XYZs= new HashSet<XYZ>();
        }

        [Key]
        [StringLength(150)]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(150)]
        public string Desc { get; set; }


        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<XYZ> XYZs{ get; set; }
    }
}


using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


namespace Mynamespace
{

    [Table("vXYZ")]
    public class Price
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string name{ get; set; }

        public decimal? amount{ get; set; }

        public virtual ABC ABC{ get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Mynamespace
{
    using System.Data.Entity;

    public partial class myContext : DbContext
    {
        public myContext () : base("name=myContext ")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<myContext >(null);
        }

        public virtual DbSet<ABC> ABCs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<XYZ> XYZs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<XYZ>()
                .Property(e => e.amount)
                .HasPrecision(19, 4);
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting query to be

```
SELECT [Extent1].[name] AS [name], 
    [Extent1].[amount] AS [amount]
    FROM [dbo].[vXYZ] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[name] = @p__linq__0
```

Comment: My understanding is the if the column name does not have id in the key column name then you have to put [Key] as the decorator above the column name. I'm doing this. Maybe I would need to put [ForeignKey("name")] on vXYZ. Is this the problem?

Comment: One way or another (fluent or attributes) you'll have to tell EF how the views are related because the relationship doesn't follow the naming conventions. Note that also `vXYZ` must have a primary key, which can't be `name` I think.

Comment: yes. thge naming convention is a problem . I modified and its working now.